# NameError: global name 'workflow' is not defined - Odoo v9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this code:

```
def compute_refund(self, cr, uid, ids, mode='refund', context=None):
    """@param cr: the current row, from the database cursor,
    @param uid: the current user’s ID for security checks,
    @param ids: the account invoice refund’s ID or list of IDs

    """
    inv_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    reconcile_obj = self.pool.get('account.move.reconcile')
    account_m_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.move.line')
    mod_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    act_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
    wf_service = workflow
    inv_tax_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')
    inv_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    if context is None:
        context = {}
```

Every time I try to execute this it throws `NameError: global name 'workflow' is not defined`

This is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 646, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 312, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 962, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 901, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/addons/debit_credit_note/wizard/account_invoice_refund.py", line 279, in invoice_refund
return self.compute_refund(cr, uid, ids, data_refund, context=context)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/addons/debit_credit_note/wizard/account_invoice_refund.py", line 116, in compute_refund
wf_service = workflow
NameError: global name 'workflow' is not defined
```

I've found that the function should have `self` as parameter, but it does have it, I'm quite puzzled at this, I don't know if this is about the way I'm calling `workflow`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is all the function:

```
def compute_refund(self, cr, uid, ids, mode='refund', context=None):
    """@param cr: the current row, from the database cursor,
    @param uid: the current user’s ID for security checks,
    @param ids: the account invoice refund’s ID or list of IDs

    """
    inv_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    reconcile_obj = self.pool.get('account.move.reconcile')
    account_m_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.move.line')
    mod_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    act_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
    wf_service = workflow
    inv_tax_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')
    inv_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    for form in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        created_inv = []
        date = False
        period = False
        description = False
        company = res_users_obj.browse(
            cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id
        journal_id = form.journal_id.id
        for inv in inv_obj.browse(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'),
                                  context=context):
            if inv.state in ['draft', 'proforma2', 'cancel']:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'), _(
                    'Cannot %s draft/proforma/cancel invoice.') % (mode))
            if inv.reconciled and mode in ('cancel', 'modify'):
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'), _(
                    'Cannot %s invoice which is already reconciled, '
                    'invoice should be unreconciled first. You can only '
                    'refund this invoice.') % (mode))
            if form.period.id:
                period = form.period.id
            else:
                period = inv.period_id and inv.period_id.id or False

            if not journal_id:
                journal_id = inv.journal_id.id

            if form.date:
                date = form.date
                if not form.period.id:
                    cr.execute("select name from ir_model_fields \
                                    where model = 'account.period' \
                                    and name = 'company_id'")
                    result_query = cr.fetchone()
                    if result_query:
                        cr.execute("""select p.id from account_fiscalyear y
                                        , account_period p
                                        where y.id=p.fiscalyear_id \
                            and date(%s) between p.date_start AND
                            p.date_stop and y.company_id = %s limit 1""",
                                   (date, company.id,))
                    else:
                        cr.execute("""SELECT id
                                from account_period where date(%s)
                                between date_start AND  date_stop  \
                                limit 1 """, (date,))
                    res = cr.fetchone()
                    if res:
                        period = res[0]
            else:
                date = inv.date_invoice
            if form.description:
                description = form.description
            else:
                description = inv.name

            if not period:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Insufficient Data!'),
                                     _('No period found on the invoice.'))

            refund_id = inv_obj.refund(cr, uid, [
                                       inv.id], date, period,
                                       description, journal_id,
                                       context=context)
            refund = inv_obj.browse(cr, uid, refund_id[0], context=context)
            # Add parent invoice
            inv_obj.write(cr, uid, [refund.id],
                          {'date_due': date,
                           'check_total': inv.check_total,
                           'parent_id': inv.id})
            inv_obj.button_compute(cr, uid, refund_id)

            created_inv.append(refund_id[0])
            if mode in ('cancel', 'modify'):
                movelines = inv.move_id.line_id
                to_reconcile_ids = {}
                for line in movelines:
                    if line.account_id.id == inv.account_id.id:
                        to_reconcile_ids[line.account_id.id] = [line.id]
                    if type(line.reconcile_id) != osv.orm.browse_null:
                        reconcile_obj.unlink(cr, uid, line.reconcile_id.id)
                wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'account.invoice',
                                        refund.id, 'invoice_open', cr)
                refund = inv_obj.browse(
                    cr, uid, refund_id[0], context=context)
                for tmpline in refund.move_id.line_id:
                    if tmpline.account_id.id == inv.account_id.id:
                        to_reconcile_ids[
                            tmpline.account_id.id].append(tmpline.id)
                for account in to_reconcile_ids:
                    account_m_line_obj.reconcile(
                        cr, uid, to_reconcile_ids[account],
                        writeoff_period_id=period,
                        writeoff_journal_id=inv.journal_id.id,
                        writeoff_acc_id=inv.account_id.id
                    )
                if mode == 'modify':
                    invoice = inv_obj.read(cr, uid, [inv.id],
                                           ['name', 'type', 'number',
                                            'reference', 'comment',
                                            'date_due', 'partner_id',
                                            'partner_insite',
                                            'partner_contact',
                                            'partner_ref', 'payment_term',
                                            'account_id', 'currency_id',
                                            'invoice_line', 'tax_line',
                                            'journal_id', 'period_id'],
                                           context=context)
                    invoice = invoice[0]
                    del invoice['id']
                    invoice_lines = inv_line_obj.browse(
                        cr, uid, invoice['invoice_line'], context=context)
                    invoice_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                        cr, uid, invoice_lines, context=context)
                    tax_lines = inv_tax_obj.browse(
                        cr, uid, invoice['tax_line'], context=context)
                    tax_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                        cr, uid, tax_lines, context=context)
                    invoice.update({
                        'type': inv.type,
                        'date_invoice': date,
                        'state': 'draft',
                        'number': False,
                        'invoice_line': invoice_lines,
                        'tax_line': tax_lines,
                        'period_id': period,
                        'name': description,
                        'origin': self._get_orig(cr, uid, inv, context={}),
                    })
                    for field in (
                        'partner_id', 'account_id', 'currency_id',
                            'payment_term', 'journal_id'):
                        invoice[field] = invoice[
                            field] and invoice[field][0]
                    inv_id = inv_obj.create(cr, uid, invoice, {})
                    if inv.payment_term.id:
                        data = inv_obj.onchange_payment_term_date_invoice(
                            cr, uid, [inv_id], inv.payment_term.id, date)
                        if 'value' in data and data['value']:
                            inv_obj.write(cr, uid, [inv_id], data['value'])
                    created_inv.append(inv_id)
        xml_id = (inv.type == 'out_refund') and 'action_invoice_tree1' or \
                 (inv.type == 'in_refund') and 'action_invoice_tree2' or \
                 (inv.type == 'out_invoice') and 'action_invoice_tree3' or \
                 (inv.type == 'in_invoice') and 'action_invoice_tree4'
        result = mod_obj.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'account', xml_id)
        id = result and result[1] or False
        result = act_obj.read(cr, uid, id, context=context)
        invoice_domain = eval(result['domain'])
        invoice_domain.append(('id', 'in', created_inv))
        result['domain'] = invoice_domain
        return result
```

Comment: what's `workflow` supposed to be? it doesn't show up anywhere in the code. Of course it will be a NameError when you reference it if it doesn't get defined anywhere before then.

Comment: Where do you think `workflow` is defined?  It doesn't appear in the posted code.

Comment: Show the content of /home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20160712/openerp/addons/debit_credit_note/wizard/account_invoice_refund.py. Aparently on lne 116 you use the variable `workflow` before it is defined

Comment: Hi, well this is a module made by someone else, I'm just trying to fix it up, part of the code is there, gonna add all the function now, Thanks

Comment: @DmitryTorba added , Thank You very much

Comment: The context doesn't really help much. The line `wf_service = workflow` doesn't make any sense because `workflow` isn't defined right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code.

Replace code

```
wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'account.invoice',refund.id, 'invoice_open', cr)
```

with

```
refund.signal_workflow('invoice_open')
```

**EDIT**

Remove following line

```
wf_service = workflow
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but still same error :(, I don't get it

Comment: Try with updated answer. I don't think so it will give same error. Looking forward

Comment: Awesome! Thank You very much!